# Edit Distance Data Structure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am new to data structure want to know the flow of this diagram as mentioned ,it's for calculating minimum edit distance between two string ,in the graph i understood that String 1 is of three length and String 2 is also of three length , so tutorial shown graph from eD(3,3) then why the graph split again in eD(3,2),eD(2,3),eD(2,2) for the 2 level of recursion . What it signifies ? Please need detail explanation . Why we can't split level 2 ,like this eD(3,2),eD(2,3).

I am following this Url : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-5-edit-distance/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnI6j.png)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking.  You should reword this and break it apart into simple and direct questions, while also showing how much you already understand.

Comment: @RandyStegbauer i edited my post , with the url

Comment: @PujaSingh Follow this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ocZMDMZwhCY&t=1457s

Comment: I'm sorry.  I still don't see a simple direct question where you shows how you tried solving it.  Please read [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so basically in case of Edit Distance, we are trying to either insert, update or delete an element. So, our basic approach is to try all three of these available operations at each point and check which case gives the best result.

Specific to the case that you are trying to understand, the following is the scenario:

```
eD(3,3) = eD(2,2) if str1[3] == str2[3] # Without incuring any cost, we find edit distance of the remaining strings.
          else l + min(del, ins, rep)
```

where

`del = eD(2,3)`, Deleted the last character of str1, and finding the edit distance of the remaining strings.

`ins = eD(3,2)`, Inserted the last element of str2 in str1, thus now we are finding the edit distance between the remaining strings. E.g. `'adc'` and `'axf'`, if we add `'f'` to the first string, it will become `'adcf'`. Thus now, the last characters of both strings is same, I have to eventually find the edit distance between `'adc'` and `'ax'`, Thus it becomes `eD(3,2)`.

`rep = eD(2,2)`, Replaced the last element of str1 with the last element of str2, and finding the edit distance of the remaining strings. E.g. `'abc'` and `adf`, if we replace the last character of first string with the last character of second string, we will get `'abf'` and `'adf'`, as now the last characters of both the strings are same, eventually we are finding the edit distance between `'ab'` and `'ad'`. Thus, `eD(2,2)`

Comment: can you please let me know what eD(3,3) means is that first x-co-ordinate represent to length of string1 i.e 3 and then Y co-ordinate represent of String2 of length 3 . Second thing eD(3,2) , you had mentioned inserting the last element from string2 and adding in string1 then the length of string will not increase ? Third eD(2,2) , why you said  Replaced the last element of str1 with the last element of str2, why i can't say in both the string the last character is removed

Comment: @PujaSingh: Yes, 3 and 3 represent the length of the current strings, as this is a recursive approach, the lengths decrease or remain same in each recursive call. I have updated the answer, answering rest of your doubts.